# Image not positioning to the left in NavBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am adding a logo in my navbar to the left in Swift but it doesn't align to the left. Instead, it's coming towards the centre.

```
private func configureNavbar() {
    var image = UIImage(named: "netflixLogo")
    image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .done, target: self, action: nil)
    
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [
        UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "person"), style: .done, target: self, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "play.rectangle"), style: .done, target: self, action: nil)
    ]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
}
```

[image]`

Comment: Is the image sized properly?

Comment: yes it is sized correctly, I've tried it with multiple images and it still doesn't work

Comment: What size is it? You want an image that is roughly 40pt x 40pt.